# ERROR while down loading glass fish in netbeans

Tags: linux, rest, netbeans

i have downloaded netbeans IDE 7.0.1 and trying out to create a restful service but cannot download the glass fish server getting an error "badly formed url:null"

Comment: you should give us more infos, like the URL your using

Answer (score 0):

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228259

think this has to do with a recent server migration, we're looking into it. in the meantime, just download either the full or the java ee distribution, it includes GF.

Comment: BTW - any reason you're downloading 7.0.1 instead of the latest 7.3?

Answer (score 0):

See the link, you only have to download your distribution.

https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html

Answer (score 0):

you should install Netbeans **Java EE** instead of Java SE. Because **Java EE contains Glass fish**. When you add server, just put the Glass fish install location and NetBeans should say "Detected a GlassFish Server 3.1.2 install. Click Next to register remote or custom local domains." (this is in my case).
Hope this help.